# sql ranking with custom ties

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello can you help me get the rank with custom ties?
i have a table of Scores stores all the scores given by the judges.

```
+----+----------+-------------+--------+
| Id | judge_id |performer_id | score  |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+
| 1  |    1     |      1      |    98  |
| 2  |    1     |      2      |    98  |
| 3  |    1     |      3      |    94  |
| 4  |    1     |      4      |    96  |
| 5  |    2     |      1      |    93  |
| 6  |    2     |      2      |    80  |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+
```

heres what the code i have searched.

```
SELECT
   id
 , judge_id
 , performer_id
 , score
 , FIND_IN_SET(
       score
     , (SELECT
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT score ORDER BY score DESC) 
        FROM
          scores
        WHERE
          judge_id = 1
        )
   ) AS rank 
 FROM
   scores
 WHERE
   judge_id = 1
 ORDER BY rank ASC
```

and the output of this is:

```
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+
| Id | judge_id |performer_id | score  | rank |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+
| 1  |    1     |      1      |    98  |  1   |
| 2  |    1     |      2      |    98  |  1   | 
| 3  |    1     |      4      |    96  |  3   |
| 4  |    1     |      3      |    94  |  4   |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+
```

it is working but the output is not what i want.
i want to get the ranking and ties like this.

```
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+
| Id | judge_id |performer_id | score  | rank |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+
| 1  |    1     |      1      |    98  |  1.5 |
| 2  |    1     |      2      |    98  |  1.5 | 
| 3  |    1     |      4      |    96  |  3   |
| 4  |    1     |      3      |    94  |  4   |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+
```

where get all the rank of the tie  then divide it by how many performer ties in the rank.

ex.

```
performer 1  score 98 rank 1
performer 2  score 98 rank 1
```

suppose that performer 2 should get rank 2

i want to compute it like

1+2 = 3 then divide it by 2 since 2 performers are tie in rank 1

1=2 = 3 / 2

answer is 1.5

im sorry for my english

but please can any one help me? im stuck at this problem.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?  `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: a `FIND_IN_SET()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` combination is pretty much the worst method of getting a rank especially it you don't set the `group_concat_max_len` to a bigger size like the manual says.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this.. what happens if 5 poeple share rank 1 with your calculation... `1+2+3+4+5 = 15 / 5 = 3` meaning those rank 1 would become rank 3

Comment: @RaymondNijland But then the next in line would still be rank 6, right?

Comment: "But then the next in line would still be rank 6, right?" Don't think so? well that would be logical thinking indeed @Strawberry the topicstarter seams to be wanting do the calculation on the records where the ranks are ties when i look at his expected results and explainments?

Comment: its ok to be rank 3 . because the next rank will get the rank 6. i want to do this because all of the ranks that judges given to the performers. will be added to the TotalOverAll Rank. and get the winner with the highest rank.

Comment: "its ok to be rank 3 . because the next rank will get the rank 6" ok just checking for a comfirment

Comment: im sorry. i dont know how to check my SQL version. im using the phpmyadmin in Xampp server. im new to programming.

Comment: No problem Nacis @Strawberry 's answer should work in all MySQL versions higher then 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(performer_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,score  INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,98),
(2,98),
(3,94),
(4,96);

SELECT x.*
     , y.rank
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT score
            , SUM(i)/COUNT(*) rank
         FROM 
            ( SELECT score
                   , @i:=@i+1 i
                FROM my_table x
               ORDER 
                  BY score DESC
                   , performer_id
            ) a
         JOIN
            ( SELECT @i:=0 ) vars
        GROUP 
           BY score
     ) y
    ON y.score = x.score;

+--------------+-------+--------+
| performer_id | score | rank   |
+--------------+-------+--------+
|            1 |    98 | 1.5000 |
|            2 |    98 | 1.5000 |
|            3 |    94 | 4.0000 |
|            4 |    96 | 3.0000 |
+--------------+-------+--------+
```

Note: For newer versions of MySQL, you would use Windowing functions/CTE (I'm not really sure of the correct terminology). I've written this for older versions, although MySQL can have issues when initializing variables this way. If that's a problem, here's another (slightly 'hackier' - and theoretically incorrect, but practically fine) way of initialising the variable...

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.rank
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT score
            , SUM(i)/COUNT(*) rank
         FROM 
            ( SELECT score
                   , @j:=@j+1 i
                FROM my_table x
                JOIN ( SELECT @j:=0 ) vars
               ORDER 
                  BY score DESC
                  , performer_id
            ) a

        GROUP 
           BY score
     ) y
    ON y.score = x.score;

+--------------+-------+------+
| performer_id | score | rank |
+--------------+-------+------+
|            1 |    98 |  1.5 |
|            2 |    98 |  1.5 |
|            3 |    94 |    4 |
|            4 |    96 |    3 |
+--------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Topicstarter if the rank order is important you need to add a `ORDER BY y.rank`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well, either rank or score.

Comment: im getting null at the rank.

Comment: @Nacis Now it's initialized, so next time you do it, it'll work, but I'll update with the hack (and theoretically incorrect) solution...

Comment: Well actually it should  `ORDER BY y.rank, x.id` or `ORDER BY y.score, x.id` assuming id column has a primary key and auto_increment option otherwise the order by will still non deterministic because you order by on non unique values now i think off it.

Comment: wow thankyou for your help :) i was a really big help for me :)  i will modify this in my project needs :)